# Android Skmaps zoom and center map to list of annotations

Tags: android, skmaps

I use skmaps/skobbler in Android app. I need to center and zoom the map to array of Annotations in automated mode, is this possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t a method to directly center and zoom the map to a group of annotations. Instead you can use the following method to simulate it:

```
fitBoundingBox(
    final SKBoundingBox boundingBox, 
    final int pixelPaddingX, 
    final int pixelPaddingY,
    final int pixelPaddingYBottom, 
    final int pixelPaddingYTop
)
```